# Changing Data Type for a column in MySql has no affect

Tags: mysql, schema, alter

I am using MySql Workbench.

If I right click on a table and click Alter Table, then change the DataType of a column from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR, apply the changes, then save it.  It has no affect on the table the column type remains VARCHAR.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MySQL has a specific NVARCHAR type, so much as a specific "type" of VARCHAR.
["NATIONAL VARCHAR is the standard SQL way to define that a VARCHAR column should use some predefined character set. MySQL uses utf8 as this predefined character set. Section 10.1.3.6, “National Character Set”. NVARCHAR is shorthand for NATIONAL VARCHAR."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

Comment: Well I in Workbench if I goto the DataType column there is a dropdown of datatypes and it includes NVARCHAR in it

Comment: but your right actually, if I just change the data type to CHAR instead the changes to take affect, strange

Comment: @RoniHoffman CHAR is a different type than VARCHAR. NVARCHAR in MySQL is apparently just a special case of VARCHAR. Just because changes were not obvious in Workbench when you tried for NVARCHAR does not mean no changes occurred. If the field was already VARCHAR, but not UTF, the change would not have been apparent; if it's character set was already UTF, there would have been nothing to change.